# TypeError: str object is not callable requests module

Tags: python

Hey guys so i just got into the requests module messing around with it am trying to find a specific response text can't seem to do it?

I tried doing the `if` with the `r.text` didn't seem to work!\

Error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/Shrekt/PycharmProjects/Python 3/untitleds/gg.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Shrekt/PycharmProjects/Python 3/untitleds/gg.py", line 12, in <module>
if r.text("You have") !=-1:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

import requests

with requests.session() as s:
login_data = dict(uu='Wowsxx', pp='blahpassword', sitem='LIMITEDQTY')

#cookie = s.cookies['']

s.post('http://lqs.aq.com/login-ajax.asp', data=login_data, headers={"Host": "lqs.aq.com", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0", "Referer": "http://lqs.aq.com/default.asp", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})

r = s.get('http://lqs.aq.com/limited.asp')

if r.text("You have") !=-1:
    print("found")
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback!

Comment: `r.text` doesn't this return the text conten? What were you expecting that line to do?

Comment: I wanna get a specific response code like page.find("This line code") but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if r.text("You have") !=-1:
```

isn't the correct way to check whether `r.text` (a string) contains or equals a certain string.

You need to do

```
if "You have" in r.text:  # Check for substring
```

or

```
if r.text == "You have":  # Check for equality
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with the line `r.text`.

If you look at the introduction to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) you'll see that `r.text` is a string.

You want to write that line like this:

`if "You have" in r.text:`

Answer (score 0):

You were most likely thinking of the built in [string.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) function

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
```

> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such
>   that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.
>   Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is
>   the same as for slices.

In this case you would change

```
if r.text("You have") !=-1: // note that text is a string not a function
    print("found")
```

to:

```
if r.text.find("You have") !=-1: // note that text.find is a function not a string! :)
    print("found")
```

or you can simply write it in a more Pythonic/ readable form

```
if "You have" in r.text:
    print("found")
```